# Account Profile Picture

Tags: account

I am not logged into any of the social networks on Salesforce, yet for some reason an account picture is being loaded on one of my accounts in Salesforce. Some of my colleagues can even see the real picture, I can only see a picture that did not load.
[image: Account]

Any ideas what could cause this? 
Tia, Lily

Comment: Try again after refreshing your browser [cache](http://www.refreshyourcache.com/en/home/)

Comment: This does not make a difference.

Comment: Maybe try a different browser or a machine to know if its a browser/machine/user issue

Comment: It happens on my colleagues' machines as well. I have also tried different browsers. The strange thing is that this only seems to happen with this one account. All other accounts have the standard grey building next to their name.